# Passing list of parameters as one string to python function

Tags: python, function, parameter-passing

I'm trying to write one generic function to run most `sklearn` models that I can use to quickly explore different models in one line.  The below code works if I replace `leaf_size=30, n_neighbors=6` with a number.  It seems to expect the first argument to be `n_neighbors` and requires a number.  I want to be able to pass the function two pieces of information: a) the model name b) one string that contains all of the parameters I want to pass to the model.

Is there something simple I'm missing or is this not possible?

```
def sklearn_mod(mod_name,param_list):
    mod = mod_name(param_list)
    mod.fit(features_train, target_train)
    print(mod)
    expected = target_test
    predicted_mod = mod.predict(features_test)
    print('-----')
    print "Accuracy of Model:", accuracy_score(target_test, predicted_mod)
    print('-----')
    print(classification_report(target_test, predicted_mod))
    y_pred = predicted_mod
    y_true = expected
    print(confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred))
    print('-----')
    print('Cross Validation:')
    scores = cross_val_score(mod, features_train, target_train, cv=10)
    print(scores)
    print"Mean CV Accuracy:",scores.mean()
    print('-----');

sklearn_mod(KNeighborsClassifier,'leaf_size=30, n_neighbors=6')
```

Comment: I think I was making this too hard.  I think this will work better with just one parameter value in my defined function.  I think it will work better to just call it like this: sklearn_mod(KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=6, leaf_size=30))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't want to pass in a csv string as your parameter, but you can use `**kwargs`.

Create a dict with the parameter name and value, and then pass that into your function prepended with `**`.

For example:

```
params = {'leaf_size': 30, 'n_neighbors': 6}
sklearn_mod(KNeighborsClassifier, **params)
```

Comment: Should add how the first two lines of `sklear_mod` are supposed to look, too.